# Query influxdb for a 'limit range'

Tags: influxdb

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM surface limit 1000-2000;
```

I.e. select records 1000-2000 only from the 'surface' table.

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you're looking for is `OFFSET`. For more information see [the documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/data_exploration/#paginate-query-returns-with-offset-and-soffset).

The query you're looking is probably

```
SELECT * FROM surface LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
```